# WQL in filter doesn't work

Tags: powershell, wql

I'm trying to do something like:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration `
    -Filter "DefaultIPGateway!=NULL"
```

But I have an error:

> Get-WmiObject : Invalid query
>   At line:1 char:14
>   + Get-WmiObject <<<<  Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "DefaultIPGateway!=NULL"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

It's strange, because when I try to get type of DefaultIPGateway values. It's System.Array for the existent values:

```
PS> $result[0].DefaultIPGateway.Gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array
```

And a NULL for the nonexistent values:

```
PS> $result[1].DefaultIPGateway.GetType()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:36
+ $result[1].DefaultIPGateway.GetType <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetType:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Could someone help me to understand why my WQL doesn't work and what I should do to  make it go?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to make the filter query work as I don't know how to access the array elements to check them, but have a workaround:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null }
```

This way, powershell will be responsible for filtering the objects returned from the query, rather than WMI doing it during retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

WQL-queries does not support array-properties.

> Note  WQL does not support queries of array datatypes.

Source: [Querying with WQL @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392902(v=vs.85).aspx)

The solution is to filter out the objects with null-value using PowerShell's `Where-Object` cmdlet.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
Where-Object { $_.DefaultIPGateway }
```